# Count leaf nodes in binary tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have written the below code for finding the number of leaf nodes in binary tree. I submitted it on GeeksForGeeks and it is giving result as correct answer, but I am not sure whether they have checked it for large number of test cases. Could you please tell me whether it is the correct solution?

```
int sum=0;
int countLeaves(Node node) 
{
     // Your code
     if(node==null)
     return sum;
     if(node.left!=null || node.right!=null)
     {
         sum=countLeaves(node.left);
         sum=countLeaves(node.right);
     }
     else
     {
         sum++;
     }
     return sum;

}
```

Comment: I think you should replace `||` with `&&`.

Comment: @Manhar The comparision is correct with `||`. With `&&` you avoid count branches with only one of the paths...

Comment: @Charliemops, ah yes. Agreed :)

Answer (score 3):

Your solution does seem to produce the correct result, but it does so in a awkward way. Assigning both `countLeaves(node.left)` and `countLeaves(node.right)` to `sum` looks at a first glance like a bug. At a second glance, it's completely unnecessary, since `sum` already contains the value you are assigning to it.

If you are using an outside variable (`sum`) to count the leaves (which is usually a bad idea), there's no point in assigning the result of the recursive calls to `sum`.

You can simply write:

```
int sum=0;
int countLeaves(Node node) 
{
     if(node==null)
         return sum;
     if(node.left!=null || node.right!=null) {
         countLeaves(node.left);
         countLeaves(node.right);
     } else {
         sum++;
     }
     return sum;
}
```

You can even change that method to return nothing and just get the result from the `sum` variable after the call.

However, I suggest avoiding the `sum` variable, to make the code cleaner:

```
int countLeaves(Node node) 
{
    if (node==null)
        return 0;
    else if (node.left!=null || node.right!=null) {
        return countLeaves(node.left) + countLeaves(node.right);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```